# confusion matrix confusion between FN & FP on the heatmap

Tags: python, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to solve a classification problem with machine learning on python. The topic is about using credit dataset to predict if the person has a good or bad credit. When a person has a good credit then 0, if not then 1. I created a confusion matrix with LR. I'm not sure if 13 is FN or FP. Could anyone clarify this for me please?
This he confusion matrix

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It is false positive

Comment: i'm not sure why 13 is FP, Could you maybe explain why?

Comment: Oh what is your positive class?

Comment: 0 is positive class, 0 means good credit

Comment: Ok it is predicted as negative, but in actual fact, positive. Hence false negative.

Comment: ah okay so 13 is FN then

Comment: yup.. i can write an answer for you.. better next time you set 1 as positive and also flip the confusion matrix

Comment: okay so i just replace the value for good credit from 0 to 1 and bad credit 1 to 0. is that right? could you maybe write a correct code version for me pls?

Comment: It's ok.. as long as you did regression or whatever learning task correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit weird to make 0 your positive class. In any case, you need to flip your confusion matrix. Let's say your test and predict are such

```
y_test = np.repeat([0,1,0,1],[128,34,13,25])
y_pred = np.repeat([0,0,1,1],[128,34,13,25])
```

We always do prediction, actual:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import seaborn as sns
cfm = confusion_matrix(y_pred,y_test)
sns.heatmap(cfm,annot=True,cmap="Blues")
```

[image]

So in this case, we just go on with zero as your positive class it's exactly like what you have in this diagram from [wiki for confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix):

[image]

The top right is false positive (34) and your bottom left is false negative.